# does async function wait for the above declared sync code to be executed first

Tags: javascript

I know that async function executes in the background while the synchronous code goes on and it comes back to that async func once it finished its execution. But does the async function wait with the execution until app reaches that line where its executed (then goes to the background and let rest of the sync code go on) or all async functions are placed on another callstack immediately after the app starts so it does not wait for the synchronous code that is declared above the executed async function?

```
//some sync code...

const asyncFunc = async() => {
await console.log('executing async func');
}
asyncFunc()

//asyncFunc went to the background and the rest of sync code goes on...
```

So the question is if that `asyncFunc` wait till the sync code above that func is executed first before it gets to the line of `asyncFync`.

Comment: _"async function executes in the background"_ - don't assume this. The code you've shown doesn't execute in the background.

Comment: What have you observed in your tests? await console.log makes no sense anyway ... since await waits for promises to resolve

Comment: Regardless of `await` before `console.log` that doesn't make sense, in general, `JavaScript` is executed line by line till an async call is to be made (am referring to your code, not every code will have async calls). So, in short,  `asyncFunc()` won't be executed until the interpreter gets to it which means any above statement/line will be called before `asyncFunc()` call. Don't get confused, the declaration, `const asyncFunc = async() => ...`, will not execute the function, only the call to `asyncFunc()` will execute that function.